# Converting Map<String, Object> to List<Widget> in flutter, dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using graphql-flutter in flutter
I think my query result is LazaCaheMap which is Map. You can look [here](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter/blob/d17b57b52d3cb985a8c8d7025a242bbcddecabfb/packages/graphql/lib/src/cache/lazy_cache_map.dart)

Then I need to use that map for GridView.
My code looks like this.

```
        List playlists = result.data['playlists'];

        return GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 8,
          crossAxisSpacing: 8,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          childAspectRatio: 1,
          children: newPlaylist.map<Widget>((playlist) {
            return ChannelCard(
              playlistId: playlist['playlistId'],
              playlistTitle: playlist['playlistTitle'],
              thumbnailUrl: playlist['thumbnailUrl'],
              description: playlist['description'],
            );
          }),
        );
```

But as I expect, I got `type 'MappedListIterable<Object, Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'` error.
How can I convert this type?

Answer (score 0):

There is a toList() method for converting an Iterable to a List.

```
somelist.map((f)=>{}).toList();
```